# WatchOS - Using live GPS and heading data to determine best VMG - looking for the best approach

Tags: statistics, watchos

Asking the interweb for inspiration.

I'm a windsurfer/sailor that races Olympic style course races and want to write a watchOS app to help me know when I'm am at my best VMG.
The Velocity Made Good (VMG) calculation is easy VMG = Boat Speed * cos(True angle to the wind). I can easily gather this and analyse my GPS path after the fact and see where I was fastest.

I have made an app that is recording the true wind angle, the boat speed and the heading. So the **CURRENT **VMG is easy.

But - where is my BEST VMG while it's happening? Remember I'm a windsurfer so the watch is on my wrist - but I'm also a little busy :-)

My idea is to beep higher as I get faster and lower as I get slower. This idea comes from my paragliding experience where my variometer would beep depending on whether I was going up or down and the rate this was happening.

So, given the VMG is only for today as the wind will be different tomorrow and the VMG for the day will be very different - what is the best approach to take??

I guess I could just assign a tone to the the VMG and beep as I go along. Faster is higher, slower is lower. That's what my variometer did.

But is there a more interesting approach using some sort of mathematical/statistic method that I am unaware of.

All ideas graciously accepted...

I haven't tried anything yet - looking for ideas

Here is an explanation of VMG https://sailzing.com/velocity-made-good-vmg/